# Need assistance OS deployment through network UDA appliance?

Tags: boot

How to create Ubuntu desktop customized ISO for network boot?

Using "Ultimate deployment appliance" from network OS deployment.

We connected DHCP server, UDA template and installed CentOS 6.4 at end client device. But we cannot install Ubuntu?

I downloaded below files from 
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/

Where do we need to paste these files? Could you please guide me?

```
boot.img.gz 
gtk/    
mini.iso
netboot.tar.gz
pxelinux.0  
pxelinux.cfg/
ubuntu-installer/   
xen/
```